# Adjust style for a rectangle as in the image

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a rectangle and I would like to put inside it, an image and a text. A design similar to that of the image, but both the image and the text are not shown. It is not necessary to use a rectangle, but I do it because I want to achieve that if I put an opacity of 0, the rectangle will either be hidden or if I put opacity of 1 they will appear.
I'm working with SVG elements. I need to have this as an SVG

How can I adjust it?

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/gqy67quc/

```
body = d3.select('body')
svg = body.append('svg').attr('height', 600).attr('width', 200)
rect = svg.append('rect').attr('width', 150)
                .attr('height', 100)
                .attr('x', 40)
                .attr('y', 100)
                .style('fill', 'white')
                .attr('stroke', 'black')
                .append('text').text('This is some information about whatever')
                .attr('x', 50)
                .attr('y', 150)
                .attr('fill', 'black')
                .append('image')
                .attr('width', 100)
                .attr('height', 100)
                .attr('xlink:href', 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png')
```

Comment: Is there a reason why it can't be html?

Comment: @Ibu I'm working with SVG elements. I need to have this as an SVG

Answer (score 0):

In an SVG, a `<rect>` element **is not** a container: you cannot append texts and images to a rectangle.

Therefore, append your elements as separate selections or, if you want to position  all them relative to a given coordinate, append them to a `<g>` element.

Here is a demo:

```js
var body = d3.select('body')

var svg = body.append('svg').attr('height', 200).attr('width', 500);

var group = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(40,40)");

var rect = group.append('rect')
  .attr('width', 300)
  .attr('height', 100)
  .style('fill', 'white')
  .attr('stroke', 'black');

var text = group.append('text').text('This is some information')
  .attr('x', 120)
  .attr('y', 30)
  .append("tspan")
  .attr('x', 120)
  .attr('dy', '2em')
  .text('about whatever')

var image = group.append('image')
  .attr("x", 4)
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 100)
  .attr('xlink:href', 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

PS: Always use `var` (or `let` or `const`...) before your variables, otherwise they will be *global* ones.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.card {
  height: 300px;
  width: 800px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cardImg {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png)
}

.cardContent {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="cardImg"></div>
  <div class="cardContent">
    <h2>Card Content</h2>
    <p>Something for the content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is an outer div with a class of `.card` containing two smaller divs `.cardImg` and `.cardContent`.  The background of `.cardImg` is set to the url you used.  The opacity of the entire card can be changed by setting `.card`'s opacity.

Comment: You're very kind, but I'm working on SVG, I need to have it like this, I really appreciate it.